# XWiki - format date inside the query

Tags: sql, date, hql, xwiki

I need to compare two dates. One is an attribute of a page, the second is a current date. The problem is, they're not in the same format and so XWQL cannot compare them (I think it's because of the first date). But, I don't know how can I change the format of the first date to be acceptable by Query Module.

I see no way how could I use **$datetool**, because I need to reformat the date during the execution of the query, not before it ( I don't have the content of the attribute ).

I'd love to find some function like MySQL **date_format()**. I use XWQL now, but the query can also be written in HQL.

So, do you know any way to do this?

### Example:

```
FROM doc.object('$xcontext.macro.params.parentSpaceClass')
AS page 
WHERE :validDate >= $currDate
ORDER BY $ordCol $xcontext.macro.params.orderDirection
```

**validDate** - the NAME of the attribute, not its value ( for example *page.enddate* )

---

### Date formats:

**validDate** - 01/10/2014 14:47:08

**$currDate** - Thu Nov 06 12:27:50 EET 2014

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not use query parameters to fill in actual subjects of the query. It will just use the literal string `'page.enddate'` as a value for the comparison, and no matter what value and in which format you put `$currDate`, it will not perform the right comparison.
2. You should pass the `$currDate` as a parameter as well, don't just append it in the query.
3. The actual query you end up with is:

   `FROM doc.object('Some.Class') AS page
   WHERE 'page.endddate' >= Thu Nov 06 12:27:50 EET 2014
   ORDER BY ...`

   That literal date isn't quoted, so it will trigger a syntax exception. Even quoted, dates have their own syntax in SQL. Fortunately, the XWiki query module knows how to convert Java dates into the proper format, if you pass the date as a parameter.

Try this:

> $services.query.xwql("FROM doc.object('$xcontext.macro.params.parentSpaceClass')
>   AS page WHERE $validDateProperty >= :date ORDER BY $ordCol $xcontext.macro.params.orderDirection").bindValue('date', $currDate).execute()
>   ```

Comment: If I understood it well, in this solution I must receive $validDateProperty before the query executing, so I must make another query earlier?

Comment: But how were you using it before? `$validDateProperty` is supposed to be the value you used to pass to `:validDate`.